# Segmentation fault while trying to sum two 2d vectors

Tags: c++, loops, oop, operator-overloading, stdvector

I'm having a task, where i need to sum **two 2d vectors** using **operator overloading**. Libraries and main function could not be changed and i am only permited to write a class. This is my idea:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Matrix {
  public:
  vector<vector<int>> a;
  public:
  friend Matrix operator+(Matrix, Matrix);
};

Matrix operator+(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) {
    Matrix r;
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.a.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1.a[i].size(); j++) {
            r.a[i][j] = m1.a[i][j] + m2.a[i][j];
        }
    }
    return r;
}
int main () {
   int cases,k;
   cin >> cases;
   for(k=0;k<cases;k++) {
      Matrix x;
      Matrix y;
      Matrix result;
      int n,m,i,j;
      cin >> n >> m;
      for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
         vector<int> b;
         int num;
         for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
            cin >> num;
            b.push_back(num);
         }
         x.a.push_back(b);
      }
      for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
         vector<int> b;
         int num;
         for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
            cin >> num;
            b.push_back(num);
         }
         y.a.push_back(b);
      }
      result = x+y;
      for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
         for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
            cout << result.a[i][j] << " ";
         }
         cout << endl;
      }
   }  
   return 0;
}
```

I tried a couple more solutions, but unfortunately everytime i compile it, i get segmentation fault error.

Comment: Most probably you're going out of bounds of the arrays. You can use the debugger to find out the problem.

Comment: `Matrix r;` creates a `Matrix` with a member `a` whose size is `0`

Comment: I can't reproduce a compiler failure. Do you mean the program faults when run? If so, please update the question and add an input set that triggers the failure.

Comment: For a reproducible example, don't ask people to type in data that you haven't even bothered to show. Initialize the objects within the program, so that readers can copy the code, compile it, and run it.

Comment: Minor point about coding: `public: ... public: ...` -- the second `public:` isn't needed.

Comment: `r.a[i][j] = m1.a[i][j] + m2.a[i][j];` -- Change that to: `r.a.at(i).at(j) = m1.a[i][j] + m2.a[i][j];` -- do you now get a segmentation fault?  Or do you now get a `std::out_of_range` exception?  The `at()` function will check the boundaries of a vector, and will throw an exception if you go out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing to `r.a[i][j]` without allocating that.

Allocate elements before writing.

```cpp
Matrix operator+(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) {
    Matrix r;
    r.a.resize(m1.a.size()); // allocate rows
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.a.size(); i++) {
        r.a[i].resize(m1.a[i].size()); // allocate columns
        for (int j = 0; j < m1.a[i].size(); j++) {
            r.a[i][j] = m1.a[i][j] + m2.a[i][j];
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```